# Como detectar quebra de linha em input Python?

Tags: python, string, input, quebras-de-linha

Preciso ler casos de teste do seguinte formato:

```
3 1 2 3
4 52 2 1 87
10 51 32 1 36 21 34 32 12 34 45
200 (... 200 numeros separados por espaço)
```

e assim por diante, em que o primeiro número indica a quantidade de números que virão depois. Cada linha é um caso de teste, então eu gostaria de ler cada uma até a quebra de linha, como posso fazer isso?

Sei que a quebra de linha é indicada por um '\n', mas como posso percorrer essa string do input por linha?

**Edit:** Acho que consegui resolver com

```
import sys
while line:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    [operacoes em cada linha]
```

Comment: `3 1 2 3
4 52 2 1 87
10 51 32 1 36 21 34 32 12 34 45`  é uma única `string`?

Comment: sim, é como se fosse digitado no input, mas tem uma quebra de linha no final de cada linha

Comment: acho que consegui resolver, vou editar a pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim - o arquivo especial `sys.stdin` pode ser lido como se fosse um arquivo comum - tando o `.readline()` vai ler uma única linha dele, como se for usado num for, com algo do tipo:

`for linha in sys.stdin:`
 o corpo do `for` vai rodar uma vez com cada linha digitada.

A própria função builtin `input` é equivalente, para a maioria dos casos, a `sys.stdin.readline` (`input`, no entanto, tem a funcionalidade extra de exibir um prompt opcional).

Em qualquer caso, num sistema desse tipo, não tem como saber o **final** do arquivo. Para contornar isso, muitos problemas de computação - no modelo usado em maratonas, olimíadas ou "online sphere judges" usam esse tipo de entrada, e colocam, na primeira de todas as linhas um único número inteiro, indicando o total de linhas de dados.

Nesse caso, é possível fazer algo como:

```
numero_de_casos = int(input())
for n_linha in range(numero_de_casos):
     linha = input()
     # e para ter todos os dados da linha, numa lista com inteiros:
     dados = [int(elemento) for elemento in linha.split()]
     # Segue código com o algoritmo que vai tratar os números
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode `passar` cada um dos valores como sendo elementos de uma determinada `lista`. Neste caso você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
valores = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores: ').split()))
print(valores)
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/wlmcwpqq-solkarped).

Para você utilizar `corretamente` este algoritmo, deve:

1. Executar o algoritmo;
2. Digitar todos os valores na mesma linha separados por um espaço;
3. Pressionar a tecla `Enter`.

Observe que este algoritmo captura um número `indefinido` da valores. Ou seja, se você digitar `3` valores, a lista `valores` será formada por `três` valores. Se você digitar `1000` valores, a lista `valores` será formada por `mil` valores.